# How to set up Apache web sever

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

So, I need some help. I used to always love programming with PHP and HTML. But then I discovered game development and started focusing on that. Now I want to learn again.

So I got all my old software, trusty XAMPP and Notepad++.

Then I ran into a problem. When I typed in http://localhost/xampp/ it brought me to the welcome page for XAMPP, so I know my web server is working, now how do I open an HTML file I wrote? Sorry that this may be a very simple and probably extremely simple question, but I am simply having a brainfart.

Where do I save a file to be able to access it from the web browser

(ex. http://localhost/xampp/mysite/main.html)

BTW, the web server is Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to C:\xampp\htdocs\

[image]

Copy-Paste your mysite folder here.

[image]

Now fire up your browser and navigate to http://localhost/mysite/index.html or http://127.0.0.1/mysite/index.html and voilà

[image]

Make sure your Apache server is running.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your xampp folder and put it here:

C:\xampp\htdocs\index.html

You will find it at

http://localhost/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi Welcome to the forums. Since you are sure XAMPP is already installed and working correctly you need to navigate to your root folder which should be located inside the following path C:\xampp\htdocs once inside this path create a new folder and call it something like 'test' inside this folder create your index.html file. Now just open up your browser and navigate using the following route http://localhost/test/index.html in other words you always use localhost followed by the directory where your file is located and lastly the file name you are looking for.
That should be all.